# Is there a function to debug draw the SKPhysicsBody in Spritekit

Tags: debugging, sprite-kit, skphysicsbody

I'm trying to use SKPhysicsBody in a SpriteKit game for what would be my "ground/platform" node.

Even though I'm using:

```
ground01.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(texture: ground01.texture!, size: ground01.size)
```

It feels as if the limits of the physics body are a little bit lower than they should be.

Is there a way to debug draw the limits of the physics body just to make sure I'm not making any mistakes?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Set the view's `showsPhysics` property to `true` https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/skview/1520389-showsphysics

Comment: BTW, physics bodies from textures are broken in certain circumstances in iOS 13. If you're running into a problem where the body is incorrect, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59961842/physicsbody-could-not-create-physics-body/60016825#60016825